# WordPress User Table Migration Corrupt?

Tags: linux, wordpress

I am having trouble with a WordPress users migration. When I migrate the users table to another database, it seems to go smoothly. However, when I login to WordPress and navigate to the users area, it lists all of the users but still only acknowledges that there is only 1 users.

So it shows the list of 10,000 users, but only says "1 user".

Do I need to migrate the user-meta table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to migrate the usermeta table also because user roles are defined there.